# Dojo: how to enhance a dijit?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

is it possible to bind a certain behaviour to a dijit programmatically?

I.e. let’s say I’m using this dijit/form/NumberSpinner a lot all across my project. Now I want to have an `onFocus: function() { console.log('hi') }` on all NumberSpinners.

Usually I would do this:

```
          … new NumberSpinner({
                onFocus: function() { console.log('hi'); },
                …
            });
```

on every element. Isn’t there a way to bind this as default behaviour for every NumberSpinner instance??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found how to do this.

## Using Extend

like this:

```
lang.extend(NumberSpinner, {
    _onFocus: function() { console.log('hi'); }
});
```

Working example on JSBIN: https://jsbin.com/sesotolove/2/edit?html,output

Reference: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/extend.html

## Using Prototype

Same can be achieved by just overwriting the prototype like this:

```
NumberSpinner.prototype._onFocus: function() { console.log('hi'); }
```

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to create your own custom components that extends from `NumberSpinner` and overwrite/add all functions and attributes that you want.

Example:

app/CustomNumberSpinner.js

```
define([
  'dojo/_base/declare', 
  'dijit/form/NumberSpinner'
], function(
  declare,
  NumberSpinner
) {

  // The declare and the references passed in the array on the next line defines what you are extending
  return declare([NumberSpinner], {

    /* Add all functions/props that you want in this object */

    onFocus: function() {
      console.log('Hi, this is a onFocus event being handled');
    }      

  });

});
```

After coding the customized component, you just need to import the module where you want to use it and instantiate it like you would do with you were using a default NumberSpinner, but then you would not need to pass the props/functions that you need in the constructor args).